# Opening a new split console hides Quake-Style window

Tags: conemu

I'm using `powershell -new_console:as` to open a new elevated powershell in a split view.
Unfortunately, my open console is hidden by that, and I need to hit the hotkey to unhide it again. Can I prevent this somehow?

My Quake-Style settings
Quake style slide down (checked)
Auto-hide on focus lose (checked)
Always on top (checked)